# Turn a php array of dates into simple human-readable string

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have an array of performance dates for an event such as:

```
2014-01-20 20:00:00
2014-01-21 20:00:00
2014-01-22 14:00:00
2014-01-22 20:00:00
2014-01-23 20:00:00
2014-01-25 20:00:00
2014-01-26 20:00:00
2014-01-31 20:00:00
2014-02-01 20:00:00
```

Is there a straightforward way in php to turn this into a human-readable string such as;

```
20th-23rd Jan 8pm, 22nd Jan 2pm, 25th-26th Jan 8pm, 31st Jan - 1st Feb 8pm
```

Note the array will always be in datetime order, although not necessarily contiguous. Matinee performances throw in an extra complication as they need to be dealt with separately.

Comment: Is the array populated with strings or datetime objects?

Comment: Straightforward? Maybe. But there are ways - and some should be quite intuitive and not too complex. However, you'll need to write code

Comment: Yup, fully expecting to have to write some php code. What are the intuitive and not too complex ways you allude to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We’ll convert the strings to timestamps with [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) and [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) and then group together the consecutive elements in the array which are in an [Arithmetic Progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) with common difference = 86400 (because 86400 seconds = 1 day):

```
$arr = array(
    "2014-01-20 20:00:00",
    "2014-01-21 20:00:00",
    "2014-01-22 14:00:00",
    "2014-01-22 20:00:00",
    "2014-01-23 20:00:00",
    "2014-01-25 20:00:00",
    "2014-01-26 20:00:00",
    "2014-01-31 20:00:00",
    "2014-02-01 20:00:00"
);
$arr = array_map("strtotime", $arr);
$_arr = array();
$size = sizeof($arr);
$val = $arr[0];
for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++){
    if(!array_key_exists($i+1, $arr) || $arr[$i+1]-$arr[$i] != 86400){
    $d1 = date("jS", $val);
    $d2 = date("jS", $arr[$i]);
    $m1 = date("M", $val);
    $m2 = date("M", $arr[$i]);
    $t = date("ga", $val);
        if($m1 == $m2){
            if($d1 == $d2){
            $_arr[] = $d1." ".$m1." ".$t;
            }
            else{
            $_arr[] = $d1."-".$d2." ".$m1." ".$t;
            }
        }
        else{
        $_arr[] = $d1." ".$m1."-".$d2." ".$m2." ".$t;
        }
        if(array_key_exists($i+1, $arr)){
        $val = $arr[$i+1];
        }
    }
}
print(implode(", ", $_arr));
```

The output will be:

> 20th-21st Jan 8pm, 22nd Jan 2pm, 22nd-23rd Jan 8pm, 25th-26th Jan 8pm, 31st Jan-1st Feb 8pm

See the code at work [here](https://eval.in/91842).

Comment: That just turns each date into another format for the date - I'm trying to turn the data into contiguous ranges.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each line and create a new array of human-readable timestamps like so:

```
$new_array[] = date("D d M", strtotime($current_line));
```

Obviously changing the outputted format to the out of your choice (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: I think the aim is to group the dates, not only translate them

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is trying to achieve. Have a look at the expected output in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output:

```
20th-23rd Jan 8pm, 22nd Jan 2pm, 25th-26th Jan 8pm, 31st Jan - 1st Feb 8pm
```

I think it is not possible seems that there are no sequences or no pattern in output. you should have pattern for logic.

Live Demo : https://eval.in/91823
Try this:

```
$str = "2014-01-21 20:00:00";
echo date("dS M g:i a", strtotime($str));
```

OUTPUT:

```
21st Jan 8:00 pm
```

For array :
Demo : https://eval.in/91834

```
$arr = array("2014-01-20 20:00:00",
"2014-01-21 20:00:00",
"2014-01-22 14:00:00",
"2014-01-22 20:00:00",
"2014-01-23 20:00:00",
"2014-01-25 20:00:00",
"2014-01-26 20:00:00",
"2014-01-31 20:00:00",
"2014-02-01 20:00:00");
foreach($arr as $a )
{

echo date("dS M ga", strtotime($a))."\n";
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
20th Jan 8pm
21st Jan 8pm
22nd Jan 2pm
22nd Jan 8pm
23rd Jan 8pm
25th Jan 8pm
26th Jan 8pm
31st Jan 8pm
01st Feb 8pm
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is trying to achieve. Have a look at the expected output in the question.

Comment: That's fine for a single date, but I'm trying to get contiguous ranges out of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think Sharanya's answer is probably the most elegant solution, although I'll share what I managed to come up with myself.

The basic logic was to create a temporary working array to hold the ranges of dates with a start and end date plus the time of the performance. I then looped through the array of dates and added to the array when the end date wasn't 1 day less than the current date or the time didn't match.

```
$dates = array("2014-01-20 20:00:00","2014-01-21 20:00:00","2014-01-22 14:00:00","2014-01-22 20:00:00","2014-01-23 20:00:00","2014-01-25 20:00:00","2014-01-26 20:00:00","2014-01-31 20:00:00","2014-02-01 20:00:00");

$workingarray = array('start' => array(), 'end' => array(), 'time' => array());

// Loop through the results 
foreach($dates as $date) {
    // Check to see if there's a match at this time already
    $key = reverse_search(date("ga", strtotime($date)), $workingarray['time']);
    if($key===false) {
        $workingarray['start'][] = $date;
        $workingarray['end'][] = $date;
        $workingarray['time'][] = date("ga", strtotime($date));
    } else {
        // Check to see if the end date of this performance is exactly one day less
        if($workingarray['end'][$key]==date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($date)))) {
            $workingarray['end'][$key] = $date;
        } else {
            $workingarray['start'][] = $date;
            $workingarray['end'][] = $date;
            $workingarray['time'][] = date("ga", strtotime($date));
        }
    }
}

// All the ranges are now in the $workingarray array, so just need to assemble them
$datesarray = array();
for($n = 0; $n <= count($workingarray); $n++) {
    // Handle situations where range spans different months
    if(date("m", strtotime($workingarray['start'][$n]))==date("m", strtotime($workingarray['end'][$n]))) {
        $startstr = date("jS - ", strtotime($workingarray['start'][$n]));
    } else {
        $startstr = date("jS M - ", strtotime($workingarray['start'][$n]));
    }
    // Handle situations where performance is only on one day
    if($workingarray['start'][$n]==$workingarray['end'][$n]) {
        $startstr = "";
    }
    $endstr = date("jS M ", strtotime($workingarray['end'][$n]));
    $timestr = $workingarray['time'][$n];
    $datesarray[] = $startstr.$endstr.$timestr;
}
// Glue the array together as one string
$datestring = implode(", ", $datesarray);
echo $datestring;

// Function to find last matching key as array_search will only find the first one
function reverse_search($value, $array) {
    $found = FALSE;
    foreach($array as $key => $item) {
        if($item==$value) {
            $found = $key;
        }
    }
    return $found;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a generic function  that takes an array of date strings and convert them into a human readable date ranges. Note that it makes use of the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class, which is available by default on PHP => 5.2.0.

First, create an array of timestamps using `array_map()` with `strtotime` as the callback function. Now loop through the result array and determine the end of the range. To do that, we use a `while` loop.

```
while (isset($tsArr[$i+1]) && ($tsArr[$i+1]-$tsArr[$i]) / (60*60) <= 24) {
    $rend = $tsArr[++$i];
}
```

We check if the numbers of hours between the current timestamp and next timestamp is greater than 24, and if so, update the `$rend` variable. On the last iteration, `$rend` will contain the timestamp of the end of the range.

Here's the full function:

```php
function getDateRanges($dates) {        
    $tsArr = array_map('strtotime', $dates);
    $ranges = array();

    for ($i=0, $len = count($tsArr); $i < $len; $i++) {     

        $rstart = $tsArr[$i];
        $rend = $rstart;

        // determine the end of the range
        while (isset($tsArr[$i+1]) && ($tsArr[$i+1]-$tsArr[$i]) / (60*60) <= 24) {
            $rend = $tsArr[++$i];
        }

        // create DateTime objects to work with dates
        $startDate = new DateTime('@'.$rstart);
        $endDate = new DateTime('@'.$rend);

        // get date start and last day of month
        $start = $startDate->format('j');
        $lastDay = $startDate->format('t');

        // if last day of month, append month name
        if ($start == $lastDay)
            $start = $startDate->format('jS M');
        else 
            $start = $startDate->format('jS');

        // end date
        $end = $endDate->format('jS M ga');

        $ranges[] = $start.'-'.$end;
    }
    return $ranges;
}
```

It can be used as below:

```
$arr = getDateRanges($dates);
echo implode(', ', $arr);
```

[**Output**](https://eval.in/91847):

```
20th-23rd Jan 8pm, 25th-26th Jan 8pm, 31st Jan-1st Feb 8pm
```

The output doesn't include `22nd Jan 2pm`, but it should be easy enough to modify the function to get the required output (hint: check if [`date('G')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) > 12 to know if the time of the day is afternoon).